# jQuery accordion won't open on first click

Tags: jquery

I have an accordion set up so that when you click on "Read More" more information shows up and "read more" changes to "read less". It is supposed to work so that only one section is open at a time. And all seems to be ok, except that if the first accordion is open and you click on the second accordion, then the first closes but the second doesn't open. You have to click on the second again to get it to open. How do I make it so that if you click on the second tab the first tab closes and the second tab opens.

Here is the HTML:
[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dll416/e9bpx6rL/)

```js
var allPanels = jQuery('.plans > dd').addClass('hide');
var morelink = jQuery('.plans > dt > a');

jQuery('.plans > dt > a').click(function() {
  if (allPanels.hasClass('show')) {
    allPanels.removeClass('show');
    morelink.html("Read More>");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).html("Read Less").parent().next().addClass('show');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="plans">
  <dt class="plan-title">1-Bed / 1.5-Bath | 1209sf | $3330+ | <a class="read" href="#">Read More></a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>massive open plan units</li>
      <li>10’-6” ceilings with recessed lighting</li>
      <li>hardwood floors and plush carpeting</li>
      <li>kitchen with solid surface countertops, wine refrigerator, gas range &amp; electric oven</li>
      <li>zoned central cooling and heating</li>
      <li>master bath featuring soaking tub, dual faucet shower, and private water closet</li>
      <li>high speed data connections</li>
      <li>views of downtown</li>
      <li>large his and her closet space</li>
      <li>floor to ceiling windows</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li> A-13</li>
      <li> A-23</li>
      <li> B-15</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <dt class="plan-title">2-Bed / 2.5-Bath | 1941sf | $5007+ | <a class="read" href="#">Read More></a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>massive open plan units</li>
      <li>10’-6” ceilings with recessed lighting</li>
      <li>hardwood floors and plush carpeting</li>
      <li>kitchen with solid surface countertops, wine refrigerator, gas range &amp; electric oven</li>
      <li>zoned central cooling and heating</li>
      <li>master bath featuring soaking tub, dual faucet shower, and private water closet</li>
      <li>high speed data connections</li>
      <li>views of downtown</li>
      <li>large his and her closet space</li>
      <li>floor to ceiling windows</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: But if I remove else then it won't toggle close if you click 'read less'. check it out in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var allPanels = $('.plans > dd').hide();

$('.plans > dt > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var $content = $(this).closest("dt").next("dd");
    $content.toggle();
    var html = $content.is(":visible") ? "Read Less":"Read More>";
    $(this).html(html);
    
    $(this).closest("dt").siblings("dt").each(function() { 
      $(this).next().hide();
      $(this).find("a").html("Read More>");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="plans">
  <dt class="plan-title">1-Bed / 1.5-Bath | 1209sf | $3330+ | <a class="read" href="#">Read More></a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>massive open plan units</li>
      <li>10’-6” ceilings with recessed lighting</li>
      <li>hardwood floors and plush carpeting</li>
      <li>kitchen with solid surface countertops, wine refrigerator, gas range &amp; electric oven</li>
      <li>zoned central cooling and heating</li>
      <li>master bath featuring soaking tub, dual faucet shower, and private water closet</li>
      <li>high speed data connections</li>
      <li>views of downtown</li>
      <li>large his and her closet space</li>
      <li>floor to ceiling windows</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li> A-13</li>
      <li> A-23</li>
      <li> B-15</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <dt class="plan-title">2-Bed / 2.5-Bath | 1941sf | $5007+ | <a class="read" href="#">Read More></a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>massive open plan units</li>
      <li>10’-6” ceilings with recessed lighting</li>
      <li>hardwood floors and plush carpeting</li>
      <li>kitchen with solid surface countertops, wine refrigerator, gas range &amp; electric oven</li>
      <li>zoned central cooling and heating</li>
      <li>master bath featuring soaking tub, dual faucet shower, and private water closet</li>
      <li>high speed data connections</li>
      <li>views of downtown</li>
      <li>large his and her closet space</li>
      <li>floor to ceiling windows</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: It's close, but now when you click on the closed read more link - it closes the other open link but doesn't change the read less back to read more.

Comment: Yes, that part works but now when you click on read less, it doesn't close anymore. This is what has been happening to me all morning...

Comment: Phew - fixed it for real now. Not simple. Could be easier perhaps using a data attribute

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Ok - one more question, I changed $content.toggle(); to $content.toggle('slow'); and now Read Less doesn't switch to Read More, why would this be?

Comment: Because it is asynchronous and the next statement looks to see if it is :visible which it may not yet be. Try a callback (not tested) `$content.toggle(300,function() {     var html = $(this).is(":visible") ? "Read Less":"Read More>";     $(this).prev("dt").find("a").html(html);});`